# Query Count/SUM on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PAR (
    ID          varchar(10) not null,
    Name                varchar(20) not null,
    State               varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (ID)
);




INSERT INTO PAR (ID, Name, State)
VALUES
('A000','Susan','New York'),
('B123','Bob','Texas'),
('C456','Tony','Washington'),
('D789','Adam','California');


CREATE TABLE GROUP (
    GroupID         varchar(25) not null,
    Person1         varchar(15) not null,
    Person2         varchar(15) not null,
    Person3         varchar(15),
    Person4         varchar(15),
    primary key (GroupID)
    );


INSERT INTO GROUP (GroupID, Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4)
VALUES
('G234','A000','B666','C777'),
('G456','B123','D898','E632'),
('G789','C456', null, null),
('G444','D789','O123', null);


CREATE TABLE SOLO (
    Classification          varchar(15) not null,
    ID      varchar(10) not null,
    Fruits          varchar(10) not null,
    primary key (Classification, ID)
    foreign key (ID) references PAR(ID)
);

INSERT INTO SOLO(Classification, ID, Fruits)
VALUES
('A Group','A000','Apple'),
('A Group','B123','Banana'),
('B Group','C456','Orange');


CREATE TABLE GROUPINGS (
    Classification      varchar(20) not null,
    Group           varchar(25) not null,
    Fruits          varchar(15) not null,
    primary key (Classification, Group)

    foreign key (Group) references GROUP(GroupID)
);

INSERT INTO GROUPINGS(Classification, Group, Fruits)
VALUES
('A Group','G234','Apple'),
('B Group','G456','Grape'),
('A Group','G789','Banana'),
('D Group','G444','Orange');
```

I am trying to get the following result from my query:

```
State|  Fruits
------+-------
New York| 2
Texas   | 2
Washington| 2
California| 1
```

I created a query that looks like this but it does not work: I know that I need to sum up all the different fruits from the tables and I have use common keys in order to this but I am not sure how as I am quite new to SQL queries

```
SELECT P.State, COUNT(S.ID) + COUNT(z.Group) as gSum
FROM PARTICIPANT AS P, SOLO AS S,
GROUPINGS AS G, GROUP as Z
WHERE z.GroupID = G.Group
GROUP BY P.STATE
```

I need to figure out how I can link the ID key in PAR table with each person column in GROUP table

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that all statements executed successfully!?
In your code:

```
CREATE TABLE GROUP ( 
GroupID varchar(25) not null,
Person1 varchar(15) not null, 
Person2 varchar(15) not null,
Person3 varchar(15) not null, 
Person4 varchar(15) not null, 
primary key (GroupID) );


INSERT INTO GROUP 
(GroupID, Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4) 
VALUES
('G234','A000','B666','C777'), 
('G456','B123','D898','E632'), 
('G789','C456', null, null), 
('G444','D789','O123','D225',null);
```

All columns specified with not null constraint. But in insert code,first error is that you send null values, second is that you have 5 columns but sent only 4 values.

You can edit the insert statements and send correct and complete values.
Remove any null value or change the table constraints to accept nulls.

Second, in the select statement, you don't need to use sum function that way, the  math add  operation will get the sum of the count. Your code maybe like:

```
SELECT P.State, COUNT(S.ID) + COUNT(z.Group) as gSum
FROM PARTICIPANT AS P, SOLO AS S,
GROUPINGS AS G, GROUP as Z
WHERE z.GroupID = G.Group
GROUP BY P.STATE
```

The above code is with independent of if there are others errors in the conditions or in the data inserted.

Last, you didn't tell us what the error you faced, and what messages error showed!.

Tell us more information to help us help you.

Comment: I don't know what do you exactly want from this code: "SUM(COUNT(S.ID) + COUNT(Z.Group))"

Comment: SELECT P.State, COUNT(S.ID) + COUNT(z.Group) as gSum
FROM PARTICIPANT AS P, SOLO AS S,
GROUPINGS AS G, GROUP as Z
GROUP BY P.STATE WHERE z.GroupID = G.Group I get an Error when I try to use WHERE after GROUP BY it states "WHERE is not valid at this position." To clarify, essentially I am looking to find the total number of fruits for each state

Comment: Yes, use "having" instead of "where". Or use where condition before GROUP BY

Comment: I believe this is the query I am lookign for, however I am getting an error code 1054 that says "Unknown column  z.Group in having clause

Comment: I edited my answer  try it. But before trying, please 
 check all code before the query is correct, i think word "GROUP" is keyword in some languages. Did all tables created successfully and all data inserted too? Then can you explain the logical relationships between tables.

Comment: Thank you the only thing that I need to do is link the ID key in PAR table with each person column in GROUP table